# How to get both the text and value of a select box and store it into the database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to store the text and value of the select box i have into my database. I can properly store the value by requesting it from the select box name itself but I'm having troubles with storing the text. I have 2 tables namely Item and ItemOrder.

Item Table

> id | name

ItemOrder Table

> id | item_id(fk from item table) | item_name

HTML

```
<select name="item" class="form-control select2" id ="item">
    <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Item</option>
     @foreach($items as $key => $i)
        <option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$i!!}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

ItemController

```
public function itemList()
{
  $items = Item::lists('name', 'id');
  return view('employee.itemList', compact('items'));
}
public function storeItem(Request $request){
    $info = array( 'item_name'=>$i,
      'item_id'=>$request['item'],
    DB::table('itemOrder')->insert($info);
  return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('itemList', ['as' => 'itemList',
        'uses' => 'ItemController@itemLIst']);
Route::post('storeItem', ['as' => 'storeItem',
        'uses' => 'ItemController@storeItem']);
```

JS

```
$('select[name="item"]').on('change', function () {
 var e = document.getElementById("item");
 var itemText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
 console.log(itemText);
});
```

I can store the item_id value on my database cause i set item_name to nullable for the meantime. I tried to get the text through javascript and i can display it with console.log. Can anyone help me with storing the selected text as well? Or is there a way to get the text through javascript or jquery?

Comment: _"Or is there a way to get the text through javascript or jquery"_ You have already retrieved the text through javascript, ie `itemText`. If you are needing to save it just send it along with whatever method you are using to send the other information to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm quite new to javascript so i have no idea on how to send the text in a method. I have no trouble retrieving the value because i can just request the name of the select box and it will store the value. But the text has the same select box as the value so requesting it would only get me the value instead of the text, I'm quite lost with how to get the text.

Comment: _"I'm quite lost with how to get the text"_ you already have the text in `itemText`, as you say _"i can display it with console.log"_. So do whatever you need to do with it. What do you actually need to do with it? All you said is _"store it"_ store it where? In a variable that other parts of javascript can use? Pass it to some other function?

Comment: Store it into the table itemOrder, I have the ItemController there with the storeItem function which stores the item_id by requesting the value of the select box with the name="item". I just need to know how to get the text from blade view to controller if its possible. I can display the itemText but i don't know where to pass it so i can use it for my storeItem function. Maybe what I'm finding is what you stated _"in a variable that other parts of javascript can use"_.

Comment: Your itemController is on the server, so as I said in the first comment you need to _"send it along with whatever method you are using to send the other information to the server"_ By method here I meant Form post, Ajax request, whatever you may be using to save the rest of your data. Any answer would need to know that information. Though I must ask, if `item_name` in itemOrder table is the same as `name` in your Item table why are you trying to save it in both places? That is data duplication, you probably should just be doing a MYSQL JOIN with item table when selecting from itemOrder.

Comment: My form post is the method storeItem that's where i get all of the data i need to store into the itemOrder table. That was my initial approach by using joins. But i can't get it to work, I couldn't access the information from my multiple related tables where each of their fk came from. There are 4 tables but i only listed 2 because what I'm asking here is a workaround and I'm pretty sure it's bad practice in coding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use

```
"<option value="
```

to hold each option's text? That way you can retrieve selected option text instead of some numeric code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the option value is $key which is the item_id of the item, that's where i get the item_id to pass into my database. The $m is the text of the item but i have no idea how to get that value to store into my database.

Comment: Can you print $items array?.You can write this  @foreach($items as $key => $i)
        <option value="<?php echo $key;?>">{!!$i!!}</option>
     @endforeach

Answer (score 0):

Follow my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  $('select[name="item"]').on('change', function () 
  {
  alert('Value change to ' +$(this).attr('value')+$(this).text());
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, i tried your code it alerted "value changed to undefined" and below it listed all the item names.

Comment: Because your options value is not create that's why it's show undefined

Comment: I'm not sure if i follow you but isn't the value of my select box the variable $items from my foreach? Or am i doing it wrong?